# porting ioctl() calls from unix to linux, error with FIONBIO

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, ioctl

i want to use ioctl() to get the number of bytes ready to be read

the way I did it is:

```
mysocket=socket(....);
ioctl(mysocket, FIONBIO, &zero);    
connect(.....);
ioctl( mysocket, FIONREAD, &numBytes );
read(mysocket, buffer, numBytes);
```

this was working fine in unix, now i have to port it to linux
i keep getting ERROR

> *error: 'FIONBIO' was not declared in this scope*

Is there some header file specific for linux? or 'FIOBIO' doesnt work at all in linux?

I have following headers included:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stropts.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <fstream>
```

and i removed

```
#include <sys/filio.h>
```

since it was throwing errors saying sys/filio.h not found

Comment: Which distro is this being ported to?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Have you tried including **sys/ioctl.h**?

This code works for me:

```
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("FIONBIO value %d\n", FIONBIO);
}
```

When I execute `grep -R FIONBIO /usr/include`, it's found here:

```
/usr/include/asm-generic/ioctls.h:#define FIONBIO 0x5421
```

Comment: It's actually C++ although i was using stdio.h :D. I've successfully compiled it using g++.

Comment: Which distro are you using? If you execute grep -R FIONBIO /usr/include, is the macro located at some point?

Comment: used #if defined(SUNOS) || defined(LINUX) and got it to compile