# Why gdb8.2 compile error on Centos7 aliyun?

Tags: c, gcc, gdb, gnu

I have get gcc8.2 on aliyun Centos7, but when I get gdb-8.2 and use
./configure 
make
then it occur compile error in ser-tcp.c. Here are error infos:

```
ser-tcp.c:64:13: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef int socklen_t’
 typedef int socklen_t;
         ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from build-gnulib/import/unistd.h:40,
             from ./gnulib/import/pathmax.h:42,
             from ./common/common-defs.h:84,
             from defs.h:28,
             from ser-tcp.c:20:
/usr/include/unistd.h:274:21: note: previous declaration as ‘typedef __socklen_t socklen_t’
 typedef __socklen_t socklen_t;
                 ^~~~~~~~~
ser-tcp.c: In function ‘int net_open(serial*, const char*)’:
ser-tcp.c:223:19: error: ‘FIONBIO’ was not declared in this scope
   ioctl (scb->fd, FIONBIO, &ioarg);
               ^~~~~~~
ser-tcp.c:223:3: error: ‘ioctl’ was not declared in this scope
   ioctl (scb->fd, FIONBIO, &ioarg);
   ^~~~~
```

As for gcc-compiler, first I install a gcc-4.8.5 by default from yum.Then download gcc-8.2 and compile and replace.
Here are my gcc-8.2 -v infos:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.2.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../gcc-8.2.0/configure --enable-checking=release --enable- languages=c,c++ --disable-multilib
Thread model: posix
gcc version 8.2.0 (GCC)
```

By the way, it's not because of not including header, needed header was divided by Macro in the code.The question is why the macro not right in compiling.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [porting ioctl() calls from unix to linux, error with FIONBIO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9609781/porting-ioctl-calls-from-unix-to-linux-error-with-fionbio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `In file included from build-gnulib/import/unistd.h:40,`
>   `/usr/include/unistd.h:274:21: note: previous declaration as`

Somehow your compiler is `#including` both `build-gnulib/.../unistd.h` and `/usr/lib/unistd.h`.

The `build-gnulib` most likely doesn't belong here at all. How it got here can only be answered by knowing which GCC you `./configure`d with.

Comment: Very very thanks for your answer! I have add gcc ./confiugre infos above. According to your answer I guess there may be more incorrect including files in that host? Should I reset this  system? Or by other way I can make the gdb succ, such as delete build-gnulib ?